# Vaadin Grid Drag&Drop change drop target highlighting color

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I need to change the color of the highlighting of possible drop targets in a Vaadin 14 Grid. To illustrate, I am using the drop mode "between", which results in a purple line:

[image: Screenshot while trying to drop the second item below the first]

How do I change the color of that purple line?

Vaadin Tutorials are not easy to understand and suggest [using a CSS selector ending with -drag-center (Vaadin 8)](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-dragndrop) or [using .v-drag-over-target.card selector](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/dnd/drop-target). But this does not seem to work, maybe I need to replace "v" in the second suggestion with something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the purple color I'm assuming that you are using the Material theme. I'll also assume that you have a custom theme set up, as is described [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/custom-theme). If not, that page explains how to set up a custom theme.

To customize the color of the grid row drag indicator:

- In your project folder, create a file `frontend/themes/<your-custom-theme-name>/components/vaadin-grid.css`
- Add the following contents to the CSS file:

```css
[part~='row'][dragover] [part~='cell']::after {
    background: green; /* replace with the color you want */
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot. If I could I would give you 2 upvotes, one for the solution of the problem and another for showing how to solve it in a clean way using a custom theme (which unfortunately we do not use yet, I will push the development in this direction)

Comment: Just as clarification when other people stumble upon this answer: Does it work for other DropModes, e.g. when the whole row is colored instead of a border line between elements?

Comment: For the between drag mode demonstrated above you explicitely need to target the `::after` pseudo-element that is used by the component to render the border line. 

For the on-top drag mode you must target the cell itself: `[part~='row'][dragover] [part~='cell'] { ... }`.

For the on-grid drag mode you must target the `:host` element (the grid itself):
`:host[dragover] { ... }`.

More styling details can be found in the [API docs](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-web-components/21.0.0/#/elements/vaadin-grid) of the web component